# Eclipse plugin and swt

Tags: eclipse, plugins, swt

I need to convert a simple java application to an Eclipse plugin. What gui library I can use in Eclipse plugins? Only SWT or can I use also SWING?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could also use swing in Eclipse but SWT is the "native" UI toolkit of Eclipse so using this should be recommended. When you want to use Swing components you have to use the [SWT_AWT](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/awt/SWT_AWT.html) bridge. But this brings you multiple UI threads which you have to keep in sync. Have a look at the following links:

- [Swing/SWT Integration](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Swing-SWT-Integration/index.html)
- [Integrating Swing into Eclipse RCPs](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t45697.html)